# CSS positioning for responsive header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a header with an image and an "hamburger" icon for a mobile navigation menu. What I am simply trying to do it display my logo at approx 75% of the available screen with the menu icon to the far right.

I have a master div container and then within it i have 2 divs which has the logo in the left div and menu icon in the right. For some reason I cannot get the menu to stay on the right in the same div container. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      #container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        border: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      #logoContainer {
        width: 75%;
        max-width: 75%;
        border: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      #logo {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 90%;
        min-width: 90%;
      }
      #menu {
        float: right;
      }
      #mobileMenu {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="logoContainer">
        <img id="logo" src="content/logo.png"/>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
        <button type="button"><span>Menu</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mobileMenu">some content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give specific width to both `#logoContainer` and `#menu` with `display:inline-block;`

```css
#logoContainer{
  width:75%;
  display:inline-block;
  }
#menu{
  width:25%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  }
#menu button{
  margin-right:10px
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style>
    #container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        border: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #logoContainer {

        width: 75%;
        max-width: 75%;
        border: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #logo {

        width: auto;
        max-width: 90%;
        min-width: 90%;
    }

    #menu{

        float: right;
    }

    #mobileMenu {

        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        display: none;
    }
    </style>





</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="logoContainer">

        <img id="logo" src="content/logo.png" />

    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <button  type="button">
            <span>
                Menu
            </span>
        </button>

    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="mobileMenu">
    some content

   </div>



    </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: this appears to be getting me in the right direction. However my menu is pushed all the way to the top and as I change the window size it slowly starts moving down. Is there a way to always make it vertically align in the middle? I added vertical-align center to the menu div but it didnt work.

Comment: For vertical align you can add by giving the exact height with vertical align middle bro... if you dont get it aligned create that queestion as separate post so that some others will also help on it

Answer (score 0):

How about using media queries to make the logo appear.  With my example, I've set the display on #logo to "none" .  With my media query, whenever the page reaches a min-width of 800px it will display the #logo element.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="logoContainer">

    <img id="logo" src="content/logo.png" />

</div>

<div id="menu">
    <button  type="button">
        <span>
            Menu
        </span>
    </button>

</div>

</div>

<div id="mobileMenu">
some content
```

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#logoContainer {

    width: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#logo {
    display:none;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
}

#menu{

    float: right;
}

#mobileMenu {

    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width:800px){
  #logo{display:block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #container {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #logoContainer {
            float: left;
            width: 75%;
            max-width: 75%;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #logo{
            max-width: 75%;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #menu{
            height: 10px;
            width: 25%;
            float: right;
            background: yellow;
        }

        #mybtn{
            float: right;
        }

        #mobileMenu {
            display: inline;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="menu">
               <button  type="button" id="mybtn">
                <span>
                    Menu
                </span>
            </button>
            <div id="mobileMenu">
            some content
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="logoContainer">
            <img id="logo" src="content/logo.png" />
        </div>

    </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```